# What is "visited" on my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, visited-days

My user profile now says:

> visited *xxx* days, *y* consecutive

What does this mean?

- The days I visited the site
- The days someone visited my profile (useless)

Comment: It means I have no life!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It tells you how often **you** visited the site. And you know when you get the *Fanatic* badge ;)

(There is already a "visitor" counter for the profiles)

Comment: Thanks.  I just saw that, and although it is not terribly useful, it is certainly interesting.

Comment: What is the meaning of `y consecutive`? Does it mean that I have visited my profile y consecutive days??

Comment: @Himadri: Yes..